# .NET 7 Minimal API best approach to modify request in middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'll give a specific example as it's my situation, but I'm really looking for generic guidance.

In one of my minimal API GET endpoints, I have a string parameter. The strings that come into my handler have had the '+' character replaced with a space character. For separation of concerns purposes, I wish to fix those parameters for those endoints that have such parameters.

In .NET Minimal APIs, we have different middleware available that might accomplish this:

```
1. AddEndpointFilter()
2. AddEndpointFilterFactory()
2. Middleware injected with UseMiddleware()
```

For example the Microsoft reference on filters, says
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

> "Minimal API filters allow developers to implement business logic that supports: ...
> Inspecting and modifying parameters ..."

And the sample shows

```
var todo = efiContext.GetArgument<Todo>(0);
todo.Name = todo.Name!.ToUpper();
```

Is this modifying the parameter such that downstream middleware sees this modified value? If not, how would I do so.

If I wanted to instead do it with middleware injected with UseMiddleware(), what would be the code?

I've googled and found no examples where it says explicitly that it's modifying a request parameter.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Hsts/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Hsts/ImprovedHstsMiddleware.cs#L26) an example

Comment: I can't grok that example. What request parameter is being modified?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to mutate the `efiContext` because those are parameters from the request pipeline. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I said in my OP what I'm trying to accomplish. I want all steps downstream of the "decode parameter" step to have the decoded value present in the parameter. Currently I am saving the decoded value in HttpContext.Items dictionary but I'd prefer to just modify the original parameter.

Comment: The only example that I've found is this one from Safia which uses AddEndpointFilterFactory and seems to modify the parameter in the invocation context.

https://blog.safia.rocks/endpoint-filters-exploration.html

https://blog.safia.rocks/endpoint-filters-exploration.html

Comment: your  middleware won't sees this  value you modified in filter,the codes handles request in filter would be excuted after the codes in middleware